# Titanium & Xcode 5 is it still possible to distribute an iOS 6 app?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, titanium, xcode5

Switched from Xcode 4.6 to Xcode 5 with titanium. Publishing new apps all go well.
No I opened an old project (Titanium SDK 3.1) and I would like to publish it to the app store for an update with the iOS 6 SDK.

How can this be done...

Thanks in advice for your answers/solution,

Erwin

Answer (score 1):

You can't easily set the SDK to iOS 6, but as long as you set the deployment target to iOS 6 the app will run on iOS 6.

From the release notes of Titanium 3.1.3:

> iOS 7 and Release 3.1.3 require the use of Xcode 5.0 and later. You
>   will still be able to compile iOS 6 apps with Xcode 5. Additionally,
>   Xcode 5.0 requires Mac OS X 10.8.4 or later.

Just make sure you do not use any methods or classes that are only available on iOS 7.